# Typescript why and when requirejs is needed

Tags: visual-studio-2012, requirejs, typescript

This is more a general question on why and when requirejs is needed with Typescript.
I have done some work with requireJs before and always used the r.js build script before deploying.
As I understand the build script which merges all the js files (modules), is to lower the amount of http request and ofcourse provide a way to modulaize your code.

**My question is this:** Since typescript already provides an easy way of separating code into modules, why not just merge the 
the resulting js files, instead of the extra step of using requirejs to handle the modules? 
If working on larger projects,  I understand that all js should not be loaded at all at once, but I assume one would still bundle modules in some way.

**Edit: To be more specific:**
Why use requireJs for managing my modules and not just stick to typescript internals modules, which as i understood can also be loaded at runtime. Internal modules vs. external modules based on amd and requirejs.

Comment: Why would you *assume* both are needed? As in, who told you to use both? Seems like begging the question if anything. If all you use requirejs for is to make a minified uberjs then obviously it's redundant.

Answer (score 7):

The only reason you would choose to use RequireJS for running your TypeScript program in a browser would be if you had hundreds of modules, but the page may only need two or three to perform its actions. We are talking serious big programs here, not lightweight apps or additional funky stuff for a web page.

Using RequireJS for a really big application means you only load the scripts you really need - not everything just in case.

For the sake of an example, imagine you wrote Microsoft Office as a TypeScript program, you could use RequireJS to load just the stuff you need as you need it. So at first, you'd load what you need for exploring files, then when a file was selected it would cause that module (maybe Word) to load, with its dependencies. This might mean you've downloaded only 10% of the program in several small chunks.

**Module Loaders**

TypeScript doesn't have its own module loader. It compiles TypeScript into JavaScript converting your module import statements into either CommonJS or AMD style code. Asynchronous Module Definition (AMD) is the module format used by RequireJS. CommonJS modules are used by NodeJS. You need to lean on these module loaders whether you are using TypeScript or JavaScript.

TypeScript simply transforms this:

```
import myModule = module('mymodule');
```

Into either `require` or `define` statements as per section 10.4 of the [TypeScript Language Specification](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=267238).

Comment: i appreciate your answer - thanks. I do know the problem requireJs is helping us solve, which is the reason one would use a module loader like requireJs in plain js. But i don't think you have answered my question, why use requireJs for managing my modules and not just stick to typescript internals modules, which as i understood can also be loaded at runtime.

Comment: @ddennis I have added a note about this. Essentially, TypeScript doesn't have a built-in module loader, but it supports both CommonJS and AMD module loaders.

Comment: @Sohnee how requirejs work with the application with multiple menu and each menu has it's own ts files and dependencies and clicking on menu should load the required file only. Is there any resource I can learn from. The same example you mentioned in your answer. I have read about requirejs but the examples were of small apps just for demo.

Answer (score 2):

If you load just one JS-File during pageload, you wouldn't need requireJS.
You do need requireJS if you have multiple js-files, and if you want to have them loaded not in the index.html, but during runtime of your script. These will be loaded asynchron and only once. The code after requiring a script is only executed after the loading of the required script.
This can be especially useful for lazy loading, when you are not sure if a module will be required at all by the user.
The other benefit is that module dependency is defined in each module, since each module that needs an other module to work can then include the appropriate "require"-Statements.

Comment: Thanks - My question is not so much on requireJS, which is have worked with and understand. I have edited the question and tried to be more specific.

Answer (score 1):

For the use case you have described you shouldn't need requireJS as you don't need to manually merge the resulting js files. The typescript compiler can do that for you. You can specify the `--out file.js` option to the `tsc` command. This will compile all the .ts files and generate a single JavaScript output file. This allows you to split your code into modules in separate .ts files using the Typescript `module` keyword and merge them for optimized deployment.

You can change the module format of what is exported from TypeScript to AMD. RequireJS would be needed to load these modules. Also there are plugins for RequireJS which do additional stuff beyond loading modules e.g. async loading text files

Comment: Thank you - I do know about the --out parameter to use with the compiler. Which is the default set up using flashdevelop, which also supports typescript. But most tutorials, including the pluralsight http://bit.ly/10ovDqb never explain why there is a need for requireJS.   So any example or usecase on when requirejs is needed, is basically what i am looking for. - thanks again

Comment: You can change the module format of what is exported from TypeScript to AMD. RequireJS would be needed to load these modules. Also there are plugins for RequireJS which do additional stuff beyond loading modules e.g. async loading text files.